# Как менять местами элементы по нажатию?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Мне нужно, что бы при нажатии на левую часть экрана квадраты перемещались влево, а на правую - вправо. (Черный на место жёлтого, а жёлтый на место зеленого и т.д).

[image: скрин]

Скажите пожалуйста как это реализовать. *Я новичок в Unity.*

Comment: Ну у вас поле представляет собой двумерный массив с 5 столбцами и N-строк. Соответственно квадраты находятся в этом массиве и  когда квадраты идут вниз они занимают ширину от 1 до 5 (от 0 до 4) ячеек.... соответственно.... при нажатии влево меняете значение на `номер столбца  минус 1`. А у крайнего левого на N (количество столбцов) .... при нажатии вправо наоборот: `номер столбца плюс  1` а у крайнего правого на 0 (с него массив начинается)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.